# Fitting multiple sets of subplots into one figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it at all possible for me to make one set of subplots (with 2 plots) in a for loop that runs three times, and then fit the three sets of subplots into one main figure. The whole point of this is to be able to have 6 plots on one figure, but have a space between every other plot. I know how to have 6 plots in one figure, but I can only put space between every plot instead of every other plot. I hope my question makes sense. As for the data that I'm using, it is a pretty basic data set I'm using for practice right now. Each pair of plot share the same x-axis, which is why I don't want a space between them.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
y1 = [i*2 for i in x1]
y2 = [i*3 for i in x1]

x2 = [4,8,12,16,20]
y3 = [i*5 for i in x2]
y4 = [i*3 for i in x2]

x3 = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
y5 = [i*4 for i in x3]
y6 = [i*7 for i in x3]

fig = plt.figure(1,figsize=(5,5))

ax1 = plt.subplot(611)
ax1.plot(x1,y1)

ax2 = plt.subplot(612)
ax2.plot(x1,y2)

ax3 = plt.subplot(613)
ax3.plot(x2,y3)

ax4 = plt.subplot(614)
ax4.plot(x2,y4)

ax5 = plt.subplot(615)
ax5.plot(x3,y5)

ax6 = plt.subplot(616)
ax6.plot(x3,y6)

fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)

plt.show()
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: You say you can only put space between every plot... which tells me you have plotting code. Can you share what modules you're using and the code you have so far that plots *something*?

Comment: @RoryDaulton I basically want the horizontal space between the first two plots to be 0, and the same for the next two sets. But I want a horizontal space between each set.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I added a picture of what I'm able to do, which is put space between each subplot. But what I want is space between every other subplot. As for the plotting package, anything is fine if it get me the desired results. I'm afraid I can't post any other image to show exactly what I want, because I'm fairly new to stackoverflow, and I don't know if google images are allowed

Comment: You should add a tag to your question indicating which plotting library you're using, such as "matplotlib".

Comment: @martineau I'm sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you for answering my questions. I edited in your result graph and added a tag and a code line showing that you are using matplotlib (the pyplot portion of it, to be precise), as was obvious from your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code makes a graph with six sub-plots. If you make eight subplots and leave two of them empty, you get your added space. Here is the code I used, slightly modified from your code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
y1 = [i*2 for i in x1]
y2 = [i*3 for i in x1]

x2 = [4,8,12,16,20]
y3 = [i*5 for i in x2]
y4 = [i*3 for i in x2]

x3 = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
y5 = [i*4 for i in x3]
y6 = [i*7 for i in x3]

fig = plt.figure(1,figsize=(5,7))

ax1 = plt.subplot(811)
ax1.plot(x1,y1)

ax2 = plt.subplot(812)
ax2.plot(x1,y2)

ax3 = plt.subplot(814)
ax3.plot(x2,y3)

ax4 = plt.subplot(815)
ax4.plot(x2,y4)

ax5 = plt.subplot(817)
ax5.plot(x3,y5)

ax6 = plt.subplot(818)
ax6.plot(x3,y6)

fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)

plt.show()
```

I get this result:

[image: Eight subplots, 7 inches tall]

I had to increase the figure size height to 7 inches to accommodate the extra space. Is that what you want?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot for your help, and sorry for any confusion I might have caused earlier on.